# What is the simple and practical example for using formatter module?

Tags: python

I found a formatter module in Python 3.4 (Lib/formatter.py). I can import it.

```
import formatter
```

Then what? What is the purpose of this module? There is no unit test for this module so I can not find any examples. The documentation is very cryptic.

```
"""Generic output formatting.

Formatter objects transform an abstract flow of formatting events into
specific output events on writer objects..........
"""
```

Is there any simple and practical example for using this module? I want to know the purpose of this module. Thx.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/library/formatter.html

Comment: *"The documentation is very cryptic."*

Comment: The module is available in Python 2 as well, I see some unit tests using it.

Comment: Also see http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html; the formatter module defines the interface that the `HTMLParser` class expects to be able to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module defines an abstract class interface for use with the [`htmllib.HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html). That module was removed from Python 3; the fact that the `formatter` module is still there is likely an oversight.

Use it to turn HTML tree events into formatted documents. For example, if during parsing a HTML document a `<H1>` header is encountered, the [`formatter.end_paragraph()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/formatter.html#formatter.formatter.end_paragraph) will be called, followed by a [`formatter.push_font()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/formatter.html#formatter.formatter.push_font) call.

Use this module if you are transforming HTML documents; like building a HTML-to-plaintext converter, or a web browser.

Comment: Ah, no wonder I could not find any unit tests in Python 3. I did not check Python 2 source. So this is the deprecated module (or forgotten module) then. Thx.

Comment: I've added a comment to a [very recent ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue18644) on the module; someone else had reported that module for incorrect resource usage. We'll see what the devs say.

Comment: "someone else" => that's myself actually. I am asking this question after sending that patch.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still confused or unsure about the formatter module, then there is a very good resource which explains it with simple terminology and good examples over here:

http://effbot.org/librarybook/formatter.htm